# Can i create like struts 2 ,spring,hibernate application in Eclipse Indigo Java EE

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-plugin, struts2

Earlier I was using Netbeans,and it had all framework in it like struts ,spring,hibernate.As Eclipse is used mostly in industry,so i downloaded Eclipse Indigo java ee ,but i am not able to find option to create application using framework like sturts or hibernate or spring. I am gonna use them in future. as i am in learning phase,also if it does not support these framework,please give me link which eclipse to download as eclipse website contain number of eclipse version which to download i don't have idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon which type of application you want to create and i am taking an example of web-application

to create a web-application all you need is to create a `dynamic web-project` in eclipse by

1. Right click on the project explorer/ file->new.
2. Crete a web-application by following the wizard.

and you are all set to start your development>regarding suport for Spring/Hibernate,they provide there plugin for eclipse all you need to do either

1. Go to market place by Help->marketplace
2. Go to respective website say spring source and Hibernate

search for the plugin and install them in your eclipse and you are all set to go

[Hibernate Tool](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html)

[Spring IDE](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/156)

Will suggest you to install using marketplace i.e help->marketplace

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is plugin based. [WTP](http://eclipse.org/webtools/) is the generic webapp plugin. [Hibernate tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) for hibernate and maybe [Akrogen](http://akrogen.sourceforge.net/index.html) for struts. (Search for 'xxx eclipse plugin' with your favorite search engine, in the future)

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Maven if you want, Maven has a whole range of archetypes for almost every combination of projects.